# Error in UIautomator viewer "error taking device screenshot:EOF"

Tags: android-uiautomator

When try clicking on device screeshot option in `UIautomator viewer`. I'm getting:

```
error taking device screenshot:EOF
```

Please help me in resolving this

Comment: is your application obfusccated? i'm having the same issue with obfuscated app, have you found any solution?